# jQuery won't POST inside window.onbeforeunload

Tags: php, javascript, sql, jquery, post

I'm trying to basically switch a boolean "online" entry in a database to 0 when the user leaves the page using jQuery's POST function. My problem is that the entry just doesn't get switched to 0 in the database. Through debugging I can see that it never executes after the isset($_POST['logout']) so as long as I don't have a typo it seems like it never POSTs to the server.

I'm guessing this has something to do with onbeforeunload as I have a simple login script similar to this that works fine.

**JavaScript**

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    $.post("server.php",{logout:1,currentuser:currentuser});
}
```

**server.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['logout'])) {
    $currentuser = $_POST['currentuser'];
    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE players SET online = 0 WHERE user = '$currentuser'");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gah, it just hit me, it's because it's sending the POST asynchronously, so the window closes in the middle of it. I believe you have to use $.ajax and set async:false in order to make it finish the POST before closing the window.